# Filter on Next.js (JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, filter, next.js

Tell me I want to make a filter on the cards that I get from the database . I have 3 filters from MUI, below is a search of cards. I want to filter the card by city, experience in years and office, the filter can be either select one or 3 at once.I tried to solve this problem by finding the key of the object by the value

```
import { Sales } from '@prisma/client'
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState, MouseEvent } from 'react'
import * as React from 'react';
import { Theme, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next/types';
import db from '../../../prisma';
import Link from 'next/link';


    type SalesProps = {
        setShowModal: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
        sales?: Sales[];
    }
    
    const exp = {
        ZERO: 'no exp',
        BEGINNER: '1 year',
        MIDDLE: '3 year',
    };
    
    const city = {
        LOS SANTOS: 'LOS SANTOS',
        MEXICO: 'MEXICO',
    };

const names = {
    OFFICE_1: 'OFFICE_1',
    OFFICE_2: 'OFFICE_2',
};

    function getStyles(name: string, selectName: string, theme: Theme) {
        return {
            fontWeight:
                selectName === name
                    ? theme.typography.fontWeightMedium
                    : theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        };
    }
    
    
    export function Cards({ setShowModal, sales }: SalesProps) {
        const theme = useTheme();
    
    
    const findObjKey = (obj: { [key: string]: string }, value: string) => {
            return Object.entries(obj).find(([key, value]) => key === value)[0]
        }
    
    const handleSelect = async (event: SelectChangeEvent<string>, setState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>) => {
            setState((event.target.value))
            console.log(officeSelect)
            console.log(expSelect)
            console.log(citySelect)
            const res = await fetch(`/api/filter?${officeSelect ? `office=${findObjKey(names, officeSelect)}&` : ''
                + citySelect ? `city=${findObjKey(city, citySelect)}&` : ''
                    + expSelect ? `office=${findObjKey(exp, expSelect)}&` : ''
                }`)
            if (res.ok) {
                const salariesFromDB = await res.json() as Sales[]
                // setSalaries(salariesFromDB)
                console.log(salariesFromDB);
    
            }
        }
    
    
    
    
    if (Array.isArray(sales) && sales.length > 0) {
    
            return (
                <>
                    <div className="cardBlock" id="black">Cards</div>
                    <div className="cardBlock">
                        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
                            <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">Office</InputLabel>
                            <Select
                                name=''
                                labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
                                id="demo-multiple-name"
                                // multiple
                                value={officeSelect}
                                onChange={e => handleSelect(e, setOfficeSelect)}
                                input={<OutlinedInput label="Name" />}
                                MenuProps={MenuProps}
                            >
                                {Object.values(names).map((name) => (
                                    <MenuItem
                                        key={name}
                                        value={name}
                                        style={getStyles(name, officeSelect, theme)}
                                    >
                                        {name}
                                    </MenuItem>
                                ))}
                            </Select>
                        </FormControl>
    
                        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
                            <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">Exp</InputLabel>
                            <Select
                                labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
                                id="demo-multiple-name"
                                // multiple
                                value={expSelect}
                                onChange={e => handleSelect(e, setExpSelect)}
                                // onChange={e => setExpSelect(e.target.value)}
                                input={<OutlinedInput label="Name" />}
                                MenuProps={MenuProps}
                            >
                                {Object.values(exp).map((exp) => (
                                    <MenuItem
                                        key={exp}
                                        value={exp}
                                        style={getStyles(exp, expSelect, theme)}
                                    >
                                        {exp}
                                    </MenuItem>
                                ))}
                            </Select>
                        </FormControl>
    
                        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
                            <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">City</InputLabel>
                            <Select
                                labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
                                id="demo-multiple-name"
                                // multiple
                                value={citySelect}
                                onChange={e => handleSelect(e, setCitySelect)}
                                // onChange={e => setCitySelect(e.target.value)}
                                input={<OutlinedInput label="Name" />}
                                MenuProps={MenuProps}
                            >
                                {Object.values(city).map((city) => (
                                    <MenuItem
                                        key={city}
                                        // onChange={event=>setCitySelect(event.target.value)}
                                        value={city}
                                        style={getStyles(city, citySelect, theme)}
                                    >
                                        {city}
                                    </MenuItem>
                                ))}
                            </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="background">
                        <div className="cards">
                            {
                                sales.map(sale => {
                                    return <div className="card" id="c4">
                                        <div className="column" id="contentColumn">
                                            <div className='titleCard'>{sale.title}</div>
                                            <div className='textCard'>{sale.description}</div>
                                            <div className='textCard' id="city">{sale.office} г.{sale.city}</div>
                                            <div className='salaryCard'>{sale.salary}&#8381;</div>
                                            <div className='btnDiv'>
                                                {/* <Link href={`/job/${encodeURIComponent(sale.id)}`}> */}
                                                <Link href={{
                                                    pathname: '/job/[id]',
                                                    query: { id: sale.id }
                                                }}>
                                                    <button className='btnModal'>More &#10095</button>
                                                </Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                })
                            }
```

MY API FOR FILTER CARD

```
import db from '../../prisma';

export default async function filter(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        try {
            const query = req.query
            await db.sales.findMany({
                where: query
            })
            res.send(query)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            res.status(500).send({ message: "server error" })
        }
    } else {
        res.status(404).send({ message: "error address" })
    }
}
```

MY SCHEMA DB

```
model Sales {
  id          String   @id @default(cuid())
  title       String
  description String
  salary      String
  city        City     @default(VOLGOGRAD)
  exp         Exp      @default(ZERO)
  office      Office   @default(ARKONT_GK)
  active      Boolean  @default(true)
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
}

enum City {
  LOS SANTOS  @map("LOS SANTOS")
  MEXICO   @map("MEXICO")
}

enum Exp {
  ZERO      @map("no exp")
  BEGINNER  @map("1 year")
  MIDDLE    @map("3 year")
}

enum Office {
  OFFICE_1      @map(" OFFICE_1")
  OFFICE_2      @map("OFFICE_2")
}
```

Comment: Is your problem in generating the correct Prisma query to actually perform the search, or how you would configure the filter cards with React?